# GWT Chrome Extension with manifest_version: 2

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

Has any one been able to make a Chrome extension using GWT and  manifest_version 2? I have sandboxed all the GWT generated files also (as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-apps/QD8_2THbo7M/discussion)) but it still does not work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first packaged app.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["experimental", "appWindow"],
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.experimental.app.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.appWindow.create('LocalWebApp.html', {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 500
    });
});
```

Vishal

Comment: Thanks Daenyth. Will do from now.

Comment: Can somebody answer this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not make GWT application work as Chrome packaged app, probably due to CSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123178/can-not-make-gwt-application-work-as-chrome-packaged-app-probably-due-to-csp)