# Can not make GWT application work as Chrome packaged app, probably due to CSP

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Keep getting CSP errors: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

The problem is probably due to HTML files generated by GWT which contain inline JS.

**UPD**: Changing to manifest version 1 helped, but this is a temporary workaroud, as Chrome 21 complains that it will no longer be supported.

**UPD2:**   `<add-linker name="xsiframe" />` does not help either

Comment: Mike Grace, below, is correct and you understand the problem.  You could hack a post-processor for GWT to convert inline script tags to JS files, but that is ugly.  Instead, I would just stick with manifest 1 for now (Chrome hasn't deprecated it yet) and push on the GWT people to fix their code.

Comment: There are news from Google on the subject (the DevMode plugin for Chrome has to be updated to manifest version 2 to be deployed to the Chrome Web Store, and it itself contains a GWT app for managing configuration). See my edited answer below.

Comment: check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469013/gwt-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2/15302669

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GWT 2.5.1 has finally fixed this problem.  The release notes documenting this are here:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/release-notes#Release_Notes_2_5_1

and they state that:

"Apps built with DirectInstallLinker should work in a page where inline scripts are forbidden (e.g. a Chrome extension)"

This means that it is now possible to use DirectInstallLinker to link your Chrome packaged app in a manner that satisfies the new security requirements of manifest version 2 regarding inline scripts.  That is, by using DirectInstallLinker to link your app with GWT 2.5.1 selected as your GWT version, GWT will not place any script elements inline in its generated Javascript, and thus the new manifest version 2 requirement that there be no inline scripts will not be violated.

I have found that SingleScriptLinker also seems to work for my own app; however, Issue 7685 warns against using the SingleScriptLinker because "This generates a $doc.write line which is forbidden in packaged apps."  I am using DirectInstallLinker myself.

Here is the Javadoc for DirectInstallLinker:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/core/linker/DirectInstallLinker.html

To use this linker, you can include the following in your *.gwt.xml file:

```
<define-linker name="dil" class="com.google.gwt.core.linker.DirectInstallLinker"/>
<add-linker name="dil" />
```

(dil can be replaced by anything you choose, so long as there are no dashes or other illegal characters).

You will need to select GWT 2.5.1 as your version of GWT.  If you're using an older version of GWT in an out-of-date version of Eclipse such as Ganymede (as I was), you'll have to upgrade to at least Helios and then import your project to your new Eclipse environment.  The archive URLs for the Google Plugin for Eclipse that can be used for the latest three Eclipse versions can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

With the above in place, you should be able to set

```
"manifest_version": 2
```

in your manifest.json file and not experience any errors due to GWT-generated inline Javascript.  This should allow your Chrome Web app to be acceptable to the Chrome Web Store (which now requires manifest version 2 for any new apps or for updates to present apps), so long as there are no other issues.

Comment: the GWT webstarter project is not working - at least the textbox and Button is not showing up. Do you have a sample available publicly that we can look at. Chrome Extension is working with com.google.gwt.core.linker.SingleScriptLinker though.

Comment: No, sorry, I have not used the webstarter project.

Comment: do you have a sample code that I can look at where packaged app is drawing data from another server (RESTful or otherwise or some other form of CSP)

Comment: Sorry, I do not have such a sample.  This question pertains only to configuring GWT so that it does not generate inline scripts in its compiled Javascript, which is orthogonal to whether it is generating code for client side only or for communication with a server.

Comment: Is this really working? I Always run into this issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8047

Comment: @notz: I did use this approach back in May when my answer was posted and it did work.  Not sure which parts of your code are encountering this issue, or how your code differs from my own.  Assume that you have already gone through this checklist and found nothing:  

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html

Comment: This is not fixed, I also hit https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8047 in GWT 2.5.1.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** new GWT bug reported: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7685, see also http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1838803/ which is related to this bug

In other words, it looks like, when fixed, you'll simply have to use the `DirectInstallLinker` (`<add-linker name='direct_install'/>`).

In the mean time, IIUC, you'd have to extend `DirectInstallLinker` and:

- override `getJsInstallLocation` to return a copy a `installLocaltionIframe.js` without the `$wnd` part
- override `getModulePrefix` to prepend `var $wnd = $wnd || window.parent;` to what's generated by `super.getModulePrefix`

---

I don't know CSP enough to give a complete answer, but the xsiframe linker is "customizable": create a class that extends `com.google.gwt.core.linker.CrossSiteIframeLinker` and overrides the appropriate methods, then use with a `<define-linker>` and `<add-linker>` in your `*.gwt.xml`.

For instance, `getJsInstallLocation` defaults to `com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installLocationIframe.js` but there's a `com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installLocationMainWindows.js` alternate implementation.

Similarly (and probably more importantly), `getJsInstallScript` defaults to `com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installScriptEarlyDownload.js` but there's also a `com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installScriptDirect.js` alternate implementation.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/CrossSiteIframeLinker.java#204, http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/ and http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwt.xml

Comment: This will work as far as you don't need cross-site XHR from your gwt code b/c sandboxed pages do not allow this. See https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/chromium-extensions/z7FSk_HEe40/RTKPQWKig3AJ

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Thomas Broyer's advice. I created this GWT Linker. Now my GWT application runs perfectly as an Chrome Application (Tested on Chrome 32 and GWT 2.5.1).

> public class CSPCompatibleLinker extends DirectInstallLinker {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected String getJsInstallLocation(LinkerContext context) {
>     return "com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installLocationMainWindow.js";
> }
> ```
>
> }

Dont forget to declare the Linker into your*.gwt.xml file:

```
<define-linker name="csp" class="com.sfeir.linker.CSPCompatibleLinker"/>
<add-linker name="csp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest version 2 does not allow inline scripts. You need to make sure all scripts are linked instead and no JavaScript in HTML elements.