# Using GWT in a Chrome Extension, with manifest version 2, sandboxing

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

Does anyone know a complete example of a chrome extension using GWT was made working under manifest version 2 by use of sandboxing the GWT page (and communicating via postMessage)?

My attempt, that loads nocache.js file in a sandboxed page fails on:

```
frameDoc = scriptFrame.contentDocument;
```

with "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL...Domains, protocols and ports must match."

GWT module is compiled with xsiframe.

Sanboxing done as:

```
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "gwtSandbox.html"
    ]}
```

gwtSandbox.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Hello</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gwtSandbox.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- GWT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="compiledgwt/modulename.nocache.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not make GWT application work as Chrome packaged app, probably due to CSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123178/can-not-make-gwt-application-work-as-chrome-packaged-app-probably-due-to-csp)

Answer (score 0):

[Here you may find answer to your question](http://lmatusz.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-web-toolkit-240-developer-plugin.html)

However when using latest gwtquery 1.2.0 with most of plugins there are strange error which prevents (like java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception) loading of full page description.